# Read colour from cell to colour a chart excel

Tags: excel, vba, rgb

in vba i would like to read a colour from a cell in a worksheet to colour a specific bar in a bar chart. My problem is that I have the colour in the format 4F9F92 but to read it in the makro I need to use the excel colour code 4076202 from the cell. Is there a way to convert the two formats in vba code...? I know that in the immediate window I can do

```
?rgb(170,50,62)
```

which leads to

```
4076202
```

In the vba code I read the colours with the following command

```
ser.Points(p).Interior.Color = arr(s, p)
```

where s and p are two runnign variables running through an array with different colour codes.

is there any chance that I could just set a function to each cell where I enter a value such as 4F9F92 to transform it automatically into the format 4076202 so that the makro can than read it in?

Comment: If you know/can calculate the RGB, then can you not use `ser.Points(p).Interior.Color.RGB=RGB(R,G,B)`

Comment: Its untested and off the top of my head I may add, I don't have Excel open right now (but should be something similar)

Comment: Actually, if you use `"&" & arr(s,p)`, what do you get? As most of the Hex I see in code is in the form `&4F9F92` so think that should work (providing it handles it well enough as a string beforehand)

Comment: Am I missing something? `?CDec("&H" & "4F9F92")` gives me `5218194` and not `4076202`. To get `4076202`, we have to use `3E32AA`. For example `?CDec("&H" & "3E32AA")`

Comment: I used ?RGB(170,50,62) which gives 4076202 and RGB (170,50,62) is 4F9F92

Comment: but if i use ser.Points(p).Interior.Color.RGB=RGB(R,G,B) it is only for the running variable p, isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

Actually Hex Equivalent of `rgb(170,50,62)` is `AA323E` which transforms to Long value of `4076202`

1) The [RGB Function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/HV080557232.aspx) takes in Red,Green, Blue Components which are `Decimal numbers` in the range 0-255 which can be stripped from the HEX value

2) Pass these stripped values to `RGB function` to get the `Long whole number` representing an RGB color value.

```
Function Hex2RGB(hex As String) As String

    Red = Val("&H" & Mid(hex, 1, 2))
    Green = Val("&H" & Mid(hex, 3, 2))
    Blue = Val("&H" & Mid(hex, 5, 2))

  Debug.Print RGB(Red, Green, Blue)
    Hex2RGB = RGB(Red, Green, Blue)

End Function
```

And use it in your macro as follows, Assuming You have `AA323E` in `Cell A1`

```
Sub ColorMe()
Range("B1").Interior.Color = Hex2RGB(Range("A1"))
End Sub
```

Comment: if I use the function and write =Hex2RGB(4F9F92) it only complains that ther is a typo in the formula and that it is likely FF9F92 which then has a result of 0. That is odd

Comment: Try Hex2RGB ("4F94F2")

Comment: hey...that gives 9609039 but not 4076202... I typed Hex2RGB("4F9F92")

Comment: Like I said in my answer to get 4076202 You have to use `=Hex2RGB("AA323E")`

Comment: oh okay is there a simple way to convert 4F9F92 to AA323E than at first ..and maybe to incorporate that in the function above? That would be brilliant

Comment: What color do you think 4F9F92 is? 4F9F92 & AA323E are two different colors ,decide which color you want to use!

Comment: oh okay...once I have this value in the cell (4076202) can I read it out with ser.Points(p).Interior.Color = arr(s, p) so that it shoudl work? Or is that not the normal input for colours

Comment: ser.Points(p).Interior.Color = arr(s, p) will work as long as arr(s,p) contains the color code in this case 4076202

Answer (score 0):

if c is the cell that has the hex colour code in it, in the form #FFFFFF

The following vba in excel can convert it directly to an RGB

```
RGB(Application.WorksheetFunction.Hex2Dec(Mid(c.Value, 2, 2)), Application.WorksheetFunction.Hex2Dec(Mid(c.Value, 4, 2)), Application.WorksheetFunction.Hex2Dec(Mid(c.Value, 6, 2)))
```

I use the worksheetfunction Hex2Dec, to convert the 3 component parts of the hex code, to decimal, and the RGB function to return the long/rgb colour code you can then use.

update - Example usage:

```
Sub ColorSwatch()
   Dim c As Range
   for each c in selection
        c.Interior.Color = RGB(Application.WorksheetFunction.Hex2Dec(Mid(c.Value, 2, 2)), Application.WorksheetFunction.Hex2Dec(Mid(c.Value, 4, 2)), Application.WorksheetFunction.Hex2Dec(Mid(c.Value, 6, 2)))
   next
End Sub
```

Comment: where to enter that if I enter in vba it says there is a compliation error

Comment: is it possible to apply this function to a whole matrix of 10 times 10? Is this in the for each c in selection in the code? Do I just highlight the cells for which it should be done?

Comment: sorry if i try it as a macro the cells do get a background colour but the background colour is incorrect.  How would I just convert the numbers in the cells not set a background colour?

Comment: the RGB(...) code is what returns a long color val, when given a cell. I've set the interior color property to be the value, just change that to c.value instead of c.interior.color